# Right way of calling Python function from C++ using pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am porting my C++ module for python from boost:python to pybind11. Although the functions are similar, getting C++ to call the python callback is not clear. I got something working, but I am not sure it is correct.

Here is the Python code:

```
import MyTest
import os

Test = MyTest.Test("Test")

def onEvent(message):
    print(message)
    os._exit(0)

def main():
    hive.SetCallBackOnEvent(onEvent)
    time.sleep(20)

main()
```

The boost::python implementation worked like this:

```
PyObject *_pyCallBackEvent;
PyObject *setCallBackOnEvent(PyObject *callable) { _pyCallBackEvent = callable; return Py_None; }

void OnEvent(std::string message)
{
    PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure();
    boost::python::call<void>(_pyCallBackEvent , message);
    PyGILState_Release(state);
}
```

When the C++ OnEvent gets called, it calls the OnEvent function on the Python script. Works fine with boost::python implementation shown above.

I ported it to pybind11 as follows:

```
namespace py = pybind11;
py::object _cbEvent;
void setCallBackOnEvent(py::object func) { _cbEvent = func; }
void OnEvent(std::string message)
{
    PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure();
    py::object result = _cbEvent.call(message);
    PyGILState_Release(state);
}
```

The above pybind11 version works. Is it the right way, should I use py::function instead of py::object? The main reason I ask, I will be calling the same C++ module back again from the OnEvent function. I don't want any deadlock situation arising in the future.

Comment: `py::function` is just a convenience class that allows you to write `f(x)` instead of `f.call(x)`.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no downside to my implementation? I need to add exception handling though.

Comment: I don't see any downside. You can use try/catch around the .call I think,

Comment: FYI, when I ported it to Debian, I discovered that call() has been deprecated in favour of ()operator.

Comment: You can also use `py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;` for RAII semantics for the GIL.